# Changing MFC List Control header color

Tags: c++, colors, mfc, listcontrol

I am looking for the simplest way to change the header color of a 'List Control' header in MFC C++.  I have found ways to change individual cells and rows, but can't get a working version that changes the header color.  This is all the code I am using that deals with the header:

```
//Initializes the List Control with four columns
m_CListCtrl.InsertColumn(0, _T("Option"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 200);
m_CListCtrl.InsertColumn(1, _T("User"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 60);
m_CListCtrl.InsertColumn(2, _T("Value"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 80);
m_CListCtrl.InsertColumn(3, _T("Description"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 800);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done, but, not without a little extra coding.  What you’ll need to do:

- Derive your own class from CListCtrl.
- Derive your own class from CHeaderCtrl.
- Replace the standard CListCtrl header with yours.
- Use custom drawing for the header control.

In derived CListCtrl,

```
void MyListCtrl::PreSubclassWindow()
    {
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    CHeaderCtrl* pHeader = NULL;
    pHeader = GetHeaderCtrl();
    if (pHeader != NULL)
        {
        VERIFY(m_HeaderCtrl.SubclassWindow(pHeader->m_hWnd)); // m_HeaderCtrl is the new wrapper object
        }

    CListCtrl::PreSubclassWindow();
    }
```

In the header class,

```
void MyHeader::OnNMCustomdraw(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
    {
    LPNMCUSTOMDRAW pNMCD = reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;

    if (pNMCD->dwDrawStage == CDDS_PREPAINT)
        {
        CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(pNMCD->hdc);
        CRect rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        pDC->FillSolidRect(&rect, RGB(255, 0, 0));

        *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
        }
    else if (pNMCD->dwDrawStage == CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT)
        {
        HDITEM hditem;
        TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
        SecureZeroMemory(&hditem, sizeof(HDITEM));
        hditem.mask = HDI_TEXT;
        hditem.pszText = buffer;
        hditem.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH;
        GetItem(pNMCD->dwItemSpec, &hditem);
        CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(pNMCD->hdc);
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
        pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
        CString str(buffer);
        pDC->DrawText(str, CRect(pNMCD->rc), DT_VCENTER | DT_LEFT);
        *pResult = CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
        }
    }
```

Using my sample code, you should see....

[image: Red CListCtrl header]

I'll leave any customization for you to finish.

Comment: Actually, by using `CMFCListCtrl`, which uses `CMFCHeaderCtrl`, the latter already allows an override of a function `OnFillBackground`. That's perhaps an alternative.

Comment: where to download sample code, with basic knowlegde about mfc it is pretty difficult to understand how to derive CListView etc

Comment: I meant CListCtrl

Comment: @BigChief If you're having problems understanding class derivation, there's plenty of documentation available if you search for it.  Otherwise, search for owner drawn CListCtrl, or, owner drawn CHeaderCtrl.

Comment: never mind I forgot to add DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP() in header of CHeaderCtrl derived class, and in derived CHeaderCtrl class BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyHeader, CHeaderCtrl)
 ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT_EX(NM_CUSTOMDRAW, &MyHeader::OnNMCustomdraw) 
END_MESSAGE_MAP()